# If $A$ is non-singular then there exist $B$ singular close to it

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, analysis, matrix-norms

The exercise says:

> Show that if $A$ is non-singular, then there exist a singular matrix in a neighborhood with radio $\|A^{-1}\|^{-1}$ and center in $A$.

Can you help me with some hint for a way to prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true. If $A=I$ then every matrix $B$ with $\|B-A|| <1$ is non-singular.

Comment: Thanks, then i ask this is true for $A\not=I$?

Comment: I think the answer depends on whether the OP means $\leq$ or $<$ in terms of neighborhood. If you allow $\|B-A\| \leq 1$ then there is a solution (answer below).

Answer (score 1):

Take the singular value decomposition of $A = U\Sigma V^T$, where if $\Sigma$ is $n\times n$ then 
$$
\Sigma = \mathrm{diag}(\sigma_1,...,\sigma_n)
$$
and without loss of generality we take $\sigma_n = \min_i \sigma_i$.
Then 
$$
\|A^{-1}\|^{-1} = \left(\frac{1}{\sigma_{n}}\right)^{-1} = \sigma_{n}>0.
$$
This is exactly how far $A$ is from  $B = U\hat \Sigma V^T$ where
$$
\hat\Sigma = \mathrm{diag}(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,...,\sigma_{n-1},0).
$$
and $B$ is singular.

Specifically, $\|A-B\|_2 = \sigma_n \underbrace{\|u_nv_n^T\|_2}_{=1} = \sigma_n$.